# Reac router can't acces params how to handle it?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm making simple weather app my last part is of job react routing is imposible for me im tryng to do routes without reload page which one will work when im clicking on button which one showing concret day weather i want to change url with week day name  here is how is my routes is looks like in index.js

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import WeatherByDays from './components/WeatherByDays';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/:day" exact component={<WeatherByDays />} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

here is component which one drawing information about weather

```
import moment from 'moment';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../component-styles/weatherByDays.css';

class WeatherByDays extends React.Component {
    state = {
        data: [],
        closeButton: false
    };

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props) {
        const arr = props.data.filter(e => {
            return moment(e.dt * 1000).format('dddd') === props.day;
        });
        return { data: arr };
    };

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.match)
        const weather = this.state.data.map((e, i) => {
            return <h3 key={i}>{Math.floor(e.main.feels_like)}</h3>
        });
        return (
            <div className='weather-main'>
                <h1>{this.props.day}</h1>
                {weather}
                <button onClick={this.props.close}>X</button>
            </div>
        );
    };
};

export default WeatherByDays;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this statement is wrong `<Route path="/:day" exact component={<WeatherByDays />} />`

It must be like this `<Route path="/:day" exact component={WeatherByDays} />`

And your switch statement is not correct you must put exact prop to "/" path that way you can browse other paths.

```js
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={App} />
        <Route path="/:day" component={WeatherByDays} />
      </Switch>
```

Comment: its better for now buth mine this.props.match params is empty agayn (

Comment: I checked your imports and you have Router imported from "react-router-dom" it must be BrowserRouter can you double check it?

Comment: yes i changed it befor your feedback buth no result

Comment: It is strange it worked out for me https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-g8j5n?file=/index.js

Comment: its noth working buth thank your for your attention

Comment: and your answer does noth apply about mine problem im about your codesandbox solution